# Why can't I post a question about math -stack-exchange?

Tags: support, asking-questions, rate-limiting

I am an user of math-stack-exchange an unfortunately a short time ago I have tried to ask a question but the system submit to me the following message: «You can only ask 6 questions in a 24-hour period». Unfortunately in last 24-hour I only have asked two questions as you can see here
[image]

So could someone explain to me how can I resolve the problem?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As a matter of fact you have asked 6 questions. That some of them are deleted is not relevant for the rate limit. It is also not relevant that they are similar; the system that enforces the rate limit is not that advanced to begin with, and even if it were, the behavior is undesirable and thus to be discouraged.

The only viable solution is to wait a few more hours (about 10).

Going forward, avoid making redundant posts. If there is a problem with your post, edit it. Do not delete and repost.

Answer (score 10):

[image]

Your deleted questions are very much counted just as much as the undeleted ones.

Comment: Okay, but the questions that I deleted are all equal: I only rewrited them in a correct way.

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro don't do that. Edit the post.

Comment: @quid Oaky, s how long do I have to wait before I can ask a question?

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro it seems about 10 hours. As the screencapture show the Q was posted 14h ago.

Comment: @quid Okay, thanks too much!

Comment: Rather than rewriting and posting as new ones, always prefer editing them.