# How can I resolve not posting new questions issue?

Tags: discussion, help-suggestion

I saw 
https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/31743/1048756

But still I didn't understand what should I do now. I usually ask questions on math stack exchange about those topics which confuses me or at which I stuck. But today I saw I can't post new question. Community said me to improve my old questions but I have no idea how can I improve my questions?
[image]

I have asked total 23 question out of which 12 have 0 vote and 4 have -1 vote. 
I am now worried because MSE was the only source which helps me to answers my questions those confuse me.

**Edit**: I also had deleted 4 questions with 0 and -1 votes.

Comment: Glancing at the visible Questions you've asked over the past year or so, I can see you asking about things that duplicate older Questions.  One skill to practice is searching this site (and elsewhere on the Web) for information before posting.  See the suggestions in Comments on [Is there a way to see related questions *before* I post a question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34539/is-there-a-way-to-see-related-questions-before-i-post-a-question)

Comment: What is precisely the error message (or warning) you are getting. It sounds a bit like a question ban, you can find links related to this in the [corresponding tag info](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/post-ban/info). (And if the question is indeed about the question ban, you should add the tag post-ban.)

Comment: And you should mention in the post how many of your questions are deleted. If you do not know how to find the deleted question, have a look here: [Is there any way to see my deleted questions or answers?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13948)

Comment: Without knowing the precise error message/warning, it is hard to say. I note that your account does not currently have a question ban.

Comment: @davidlowryduda my account is now unban. I edited my few posts and got some(2 or 3) up votes. So my account have no question ban now.